# Specifying a css class for a field of a generic form

Tags: python, css, django

I have the CRUD views, one of them looks like this:

```
#model
class Model(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField()
    field2 = models.CharField()



#view
class Model1CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Model1
    fields = ['field1', 'field2']

#template
and model1_form.html

    <form action="{% url 'model1_new' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

I need to specify a css class for field1, how can I do that?

Comment: Not a direct answer but https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks is useful. Also fields have IDs, sometimes you might want to use one for CSS.

Comment: @Kos, for such a simple thing I'll have to install all that? No, thanks.

Comment: That's not what I meant. The lib is useful because Django normally encourages setting field classes in the `Widget` instances for a given `Form`, while it's (arguably) more logical to put that in templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `Form` and modify the `attrs` of that fields widget. There are two common ways of doing this. In either case, you need to create a custom `Form` and tell your `View` to use that form:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import FooModel

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field1'].widget.attrs = { 'class': 'fooclass' }

    class Meta:
        model = FooModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
```

or

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import FooModel

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'fooclass';}))

    class Meta:
        model = FooModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
```

then in your **views.py**:

```
from myapp.forms import FooForm

class Model1CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Model1
    fields = ['field1', 'field2']
    form_class = FooForm
```

Comment: in `Model1CreateView`, does it have to be `form_class= FooForm` or `form= FooForm`?

Comment: `form_class`. You can see all of the attribute and methods that a `CreatView` provides here: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/. Also, I forgot to add your second field to the form. I've updated

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a form explicitly if you want to do this.

```
class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    field1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myclass'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']

class Model1CreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = Model1Form
    model = Model1
```

Comment: shouldn't I specify field2 in Model1Form as well?

Comment: If you're not changing anything from the default (as defined in the model), then no there's no reason to.

Comment: also it throws an error: `Model1CreateView is missing a queryset`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Apologies, should be form_class and you still need model.